# AlarmManager does not wake tablet device from sleep

Tags: android, alarmmanager, commonsware-cwac

I cannot get some Android devices to wake up using the AlarmManager. Following the advice in other StackOverflow posts, I am testing CommonsWares [cwac-wakeful](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful) demo unmodified, compiled in Eclipse, and sent directly to my tablet devices.

When the screen is on the app wakes every 15 minutes and dutifully writes a log message, if I switch the screen off (short press on the power button) and remove the USB cable, then reconnect say 30 minutes later, there are no log messages for the period during which the device was asleep. The alarm does trigger immediately after I wake the device up (according to the log message timestamp). If I leave the USB cable connected the alarm does trigger even with the screen off, presumably because the device is in "debug" mode.

I have seen this behaviour on an older Android 2.2 tablet and I think it might be a bug in the hardware or OS common to both devices. However, I would like to rule out a bug in the cwac-wakeful utility and "operator error" if possible.

Has anyone else seen this behaviour and have any suggestions about further diagnostics or remedies?

Comment: I am not aware of any bugs in `WakefulIntentService`, and it is being used by a fair number of developers. What specifically is the "older Android 2.2 tablet"?

Comment: The two tablets in question are an Ampe A90 (AllWinner A10 CPU) with Android 4.0.3 and a Viewsonic G Tablet running an out-of-date VEGAn-TAB ROM (but the same behaviour was observed with the stock ROM).

Comment: I was also surprised that this wasn't more commonly reported, which is why I triple-checked for operator error. My theory is that most devices with mobile radios have different power management, and so WiFi-only tablets are a less common Android platform.

Comment: I can tell you that it works fine on a WiFi-only ASUS Transformer Prime running 4.0.3 -- I just tried it. Hence, I doubt that it has anything to do with radios.

Comment: Same problem here. Works flawlessly on my Android phone, but not on my tablet. Occasionally tablet doesn't seem to wake up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually get the same behaviour when I set the built-in clock alarm from the home page, i.e. the A90 and the VEGAn-TAB don't wake up until the next manual power on. Therefore it must be a fundamental problem with the tablets rather than a bug in AlarmManager or WakefulIntentService.